# Can i edit operting system of any electrical device

Tags: flash, installation, architecture, reverse-engineering

## How to Edit any devices system software

**
Hey everyone I have a big problem. I can't sleep every time I think about how to edit the device system I always can't understand it
**

How to preview the script of any electrical device using usb and phone or some special device. And how to edit the system of this device when the script is not open source ?

I was looking for everything on the internet. I learned "Flashing" and flashing works differently on all devices :(

I don't have a computer, I only have a phone and a Raspberry Pi 3 B that already has a Linux operating system installed on it